# Why is the inference of a generic type not "transitive"?

Tags: generics, rust, type-inference

When I try to compile this code:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn test_eq<T, U, B>(t: T, u: U) -> bool
where
    T: Borrow<B>,
    U: Borrow<B>,
    B: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
{
    t.borrow() == u.borrow()
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1, 2, 3];

    assert!(test_eq(my_vec, [1, 2, 3]));
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `std::vec::Vec<i32>: std::borrow::Borrow<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
15 |     assert!(test_eq(my_vec, [1, 2, 3]));
   |             ^^^^^^^
   |
```

Obviously, `[T]` is a good candidate for `B` because:

- `Vec<T>` implements `Borrow<[T]>`
- `[T, 3]` implements `Borrow<[T]>`
- `[T]` implements `PartialEq<[T]>`

and my code compiles if I explicitly specify the types:

```
assert!(test_eq::<Vec<i32>, [i32; 3], [i32]>(my_vec, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Why does this code fail to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E0283

> This error occurs when the compiler doesn't have enough information to unambiguously choose an implementation.

In this example the compiler is not able to infer that `B` is a slice type `[T]`, You have at least to specify that information with the annotation `[_]`:

```
assert!(test_eq::<_, _, [_]>(my_vec, [1, 2, 3] ));
```